# C# Get JSON Keys from Array without Model

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON file

```json
{
    "RandonName": [
      {
        "RandomKey1": "Data",
        "RandomKey2": "Data",
        "RandomKey3": "Data",
        "RandomKey4": "Data",
        "RandomKey5": "Data"

      },
      {
        "RandomKey1": "Data",
        "RandomKey2": "Data",
        "RandomKey3": "Data",
        "RandomKey4": "Data",
        "RandomKey5": "Data"

      }
    ]
}
```

My Deserializer

```
JsonTextReader JTR = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
JsonSerializer JS = new JsonSerializer();

var dictionary = JS.Deserialize(JTR) as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, JToken>>;
```

My Print, output is RandonName

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in sourceRoot)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);               
}
```

Can I get somehow all Key names inside the array?

Comment: Does all objects under the `RandonName` collection have the same properties? Like `RandomKey1`, ..., `RandomKey5`

Comment: Yes they have, just made it more abstract probably to much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JsonSerializer.Deserialize()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) is a static method. You don't need to create instance for `JsonSerializer`.

Meanwhile `JToken` is from `Newtonsoft.Json`. I think would be great not to mix up with `System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json`.

And deserialize as `Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>` type.

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>> dictionary = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>>(JTR);

// Iterate for first item in RandonName dictionary
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary["RandonName"][0])
{
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
}
                
// Iterate for all items in RandonName dictionary
foreach (var items in dictionary["RandonName"])
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
        Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value);
    }       
}
```

[Sample .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8INoyn)

To get all Keys (from the first item):

```cs
dictionary["RandonName"][0].Keys
```

To get all keys from every item in the list:

```cs
using System.Linq;

dictionary["RandonName"].SelectMany(x => x.Keys).ToList();
```

Comment: Okay, that would work, but what If I need to stay with the JToken?

Answer (score 1):

```
    string json = @"{
    'RandonName': [

      {
        'RandomKey1': 'Data',
        'RandomKey2': 'Data',
        'RandomKey3': 'Data',
        'RandomKey4': 'Data',
        'RandomKey5': 'Data'


      },
      {
        'RandomKey1': 'Data',
        'RandomKey2': 'Data',
        'RandomKey3': 'Data',
        'RandomKey4': 'Data',
        'RandomKey5': 'Data'
      }
    ]
}
";
    Console.WriteLine(
      JObject.Parse(json)["RandonName"][0].Children<JProperty>().Select(x => x.Name));
```

Will print out:

```
RandomKey1
RandomKey2
RandomKey3
RandomKey4
RandomKey5
```

The key to the one-liner is to cast the children of the first `JObject` to `JProperty`.

Comment: Okay what if "RandomName" is not known?

Comment: According to your code, you are able to get the informationen about the correct name of 'RandomName'. Then in the next step you can iterate over every random name you found.

Comment: The code assumes `RadonName` can be found . I understood the OP's question was about getting the children of `RandonName`. That was the main part of the code given in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only just the property names from the first object then you can take advantage of [Json.NET's Linq](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm)

```
var semiParsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
var collection = (JArray)semiParsedJson["RandonName"];
var firstObject = (JObject)collection.First();
foreach (var property in firstObject.Properties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
}
```